# Android Widget with Glance make around corners for SDK lower than 31

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-jetpack-compose

[Announcing Jetpack Glance Alpha for app widgets](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/12/announcing-jetpack-glance-alpha-for-app.html). However rounded corners do not work for SDK lower than 31 (Android 12).
Ideally, you would want to change the background color with rounded corners programmatically.

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue. And, I solved the problem with background drawable. Give background drawable to your root.

> MyWidgetClass.kt

```
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Column(
            modifier = GlanceModifier
                .width(170.dp).height(130.dp)
                .background(ImageProvider(R.drawable.background_widget))
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            //...
        }
    }
```

> background_widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: This is the best solution. The only thing that will work differently with this version of rounded corners vs what you get on sdk 31+ is clipping for child views outside the radius